# vba to save as CSV

Tags: excel, csv, export-to-csv, vba

I found code to save a single sheet as CSV.
But I am getting error:
Run-time error '1004'
Cannot access read-only document 'MasterCallOneList.CSV'

How to fix?

The document is actually a new document that does not exist, so I don't know why it would say that the document is read-only.

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim strFullName As String
strFullName = Application.Path + "\MasterOneCallList.CSV"
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Combined").Copy
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=strFullName, FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=True
ActiveWorkbook.Close

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Comment: Just a thought, if the document is a new document, is `strFullName = Application.Path + "\MasterOneCallList.CSV"`-going to work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could be due to protection levels in the application.path directory.

Have you tried

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim strFullName As String
strFullName = ThisWorkbook.Path + "\MasterOneCallList.CSV"
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Combined").Copy
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=strFullName, FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=True
ActiveWorkbook.Close

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Answer (score 0):

```
strFullName = Application.Path + "\MasterOneCallList.CSV"
```

This could be the error, the path name would be the ms_office excel folder. Try using an actual folder path string and the code should work. If it does work, you would have to figure a way to get an actual path string.

```
    Sub Button1_Click()

    Dim strFullName As String

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    strFullName = "C:\Users\dmorrison\Downloads\TestKryztof" + "\MasterOneCallList.CSV"
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Combined").Copy
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=strFullName, FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=True
    ActiveWorkbook.Close

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```